# Does Pandas release the last chunk from memory after loading the next one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take the code below for example. Assuming the chunk iterator renders 10 chunks, the **for loop** will load all of them into memory (one after another) or Python will work efficiently releasing one after the oter?

```
df_iter = pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=100)

for chunk in df_iter:
  chunk.to_sql(table, engine)
```

I've made some tests with files bigger than memory using the code above and got memory overflow. Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm seeing what you're seeing, where more and more memory gets used in the program as the loop iterates. I wasn't expecting this to be the case. I tried keeping track of current memory using the `tracemalloc` library and the memory usage does increase.

I tried to pre-allocate all the memory I'd need outside of the for-loop so no accidental memory accumulation occurred, but I could have made a mistake somehow

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#followed example on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/monitoring-memory-usage-of-a-running-python-program/
import tracemalloc

#create an example csv to read back in with chunks
nrows = 1000000
out_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age':np.random.randint(0,10,nrows),
    'height':np.random.randint(0,10,nrows),
})
out_df.to_csv('test_out.csv')

chunksize = 10000
pre_alloc_data = {i:0 for i in range(0,nrows//chunksize,10)}

# starting the monitoring 
tracemalloc.start()

df_iter = pd.read_csv('test_out.csv', chunksize=chunksize)


for i,chunk in enumerate(df_iter):
    # store the current memory usage every 10 iterations
    if i%10 == 0:
        pre_alloc_data[i] = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()[0]
            
# stopping the library
tracemalloc.stop()

print(pre_alloc_data)
```

Output

```
{0: 1047984, 10: 1049208, 20: 1049532, 30: 1049832, 40: 1050596, 50: 1051720, 60: 1052692, 70: 1053696, 80: 1054732, 90: 1055800}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be like that, right? Seems like a bug or something...

Comment: I think panda does not support to remove the chunk from memory, it is designed to load large files but not results in large files.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv():
    *Do something*
```

And not:

```
chunks = pd.read_csv()
for chunk in chunk:
    *Do something*
```